# Sorting, pagination and filter in mat-table with custom datasource?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I'm trying to sort, paginate and filter table with Angular Material "mat-table" getting its data from custom datasource.

I'm using angular 5.2.5 with chrome navigator

This is the component...

```
constructor(
    private jobsService: JobsService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private aps: ApplicationsService,
    private bindingsService: BindingsService
  ) {
    this.jobs = new Jobs(jobsService);
    this.jobsDataSource = new JobDataSource(this.jobs);
  }
```

This is my own datasource (JobDataSource)

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { Jobs } from './jobs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Job } from './job.model';
import { SatelliteResponse } from './satelliteresponse.model';

export class JobDataSource extends DataSource<SatelliteResponse> {

    constructor(private jobs: Jobs) {
        super();
    }

    /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
    connect(): Observable<SatelliteResponse[]> {
        const displayDataChanges = [
            this.jobs.dataChange,
            this.jobs.jobList
        ];

        return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map((data) => {
            return data;
        });
    }

    disconnect() { }

}
```

The thing I need is like the example...

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
```

so... I think I need my JobDataSource class extends MatTableDataSource (because  MatTableDataSource is a child of DataSource). I change the code, but it shows me an error saying "connect" is not a method for MatTableDataSource.

How can I achieve it? How can I modify JobDataSource to still getting data with an observable and also get MatTableDataSource properties for filtering, sorting... etc.

Thank you

Comment: Is there anyone deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

You must first implement a service to get the data from your http call and then implement the datasource class from @angular/cdk/collections - I think that is where your confusion lies please see https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/ - It explains very clearly how to implement a custom data source for mat table

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thanks lisa! In this article told... "In our case, all the filtering, sorting and pagination will be happening on the server, so we will be building our own Angular CDK reactive data source from first principles." This is not may case. I want to order, filter and sort with data in the client part

Answer (score -1):

In that case, you don't need an implementation of DataSource. This examples will work fine: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples